# How can I test with stdin if Ctrl + d has been pressed?

Tags: java, while-loop, stdin, terminate

I'm reading from standard input using the following loop:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

while (stdin.hasNextLine() && stdin.nextLine() != null) {

        String line = stdin.nextLine();

        if (!(line.contains("#"))) {
            input.add(line);
        }

        if (line.contentEquals("q")) {
            break;
        }

 }
```

Now this is easy to terminate if I simply type `q` and press enter, however I'm supposed to terminate the program when the user presses `Ctrl + d` on a new line. I can't get this to work, when I press `Ctrl + d` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `hasNextLine()` and `hasLine()` wait for the user to input "enter".

Ctrl-D is not ... enter.

So you have to look into means that go "character by character" for example.

Maybe `scanner.next()` will return something more useful instead.

Beyond that, things are even more complicated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940564/how-to-exit-the-program-when-ctrld-is-entered-in-java) for example.

Thus, the real, not so helpful answer is actually: Java scanner and "ctrl-something" keystrokes are not exactly best friends.

You could probably look into some libraries providing [curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications) like functionality instead.

Comment: If I change the while condition to `while(stdin.next() != null)` I get a `NoSuchElementException` exception on `Ctrl + d`

Comment: Is there something else you suggest I can use to read from standard input instead of the scanner?

Comment: So should i basically try to catch that exception and assume that when it happens all the input has been supplied?

Comment: That would be one option. The other option would be to change from "scanner" to something more "curses" like ... see my updates again!

Comment: I will accept it, gotta wait 6 minutes though