# EOF not working in data files to save value

Tags: java, data-structures, netbeans, data-files

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream istream;        
    int c;
    final int EOF = -1;
    istream = System.in; 
    FileWriter outFile =  new FileWriter("C:/Users/boamb/Documents/NetBeansProjects/DSA_BSE20BFT/src/week7/Data.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(outFile);
    System.out.println("Enter fruits to store in data File – Press Ctrl+Z to end ");    
    while ((c = istream.read()) != EOF)
    bWriter.write(c);
    bWriter.close();
    }
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to insert data in a file through the system output in the NETBEANS IDE but the issue is when i am pressing CTRL+Z it is not working, the program is still running and when i stop it manually there are no data saved in the file. This is my piece of code.

Comment: EOF is triggered by [ctrl-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940564/how-to-exit-the-program-when-ctrld-is-entered-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't understand what is the reason for relying on EOF when your logic says "Enter fruits". I mean you should read a string, not a byte-by-byte and in this case terminator will be also some string value, "end" for example:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter( "C:/Users/boamb/Documents/NetBeansProjects/DSA_BSE20BFT/src/week7/Data.txt", true );
    try ( BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter( outFile ); ){
        String line;
        while( true ){
            System.out.println( "Enter fruits to store in data File – Enter 'end' to end " );
            line = br.readLine();
            if( "end".equals( line ) ){
                break;
            }
            bWriter.write( line );
            bWriter.newLine();
        }
        bWriter.flush();
    }
}
```